What Flavors / DEs have Accessibility Features Similar to Compiz?
I have been an Ubuntu user for over a decade, specifically Ubuntu MATE for the last 5 or so years.  I am also visually impaired.  In the past, I have installed Compiz on my Mate installation, then switched the Window Manager via Mate-Tweak to Compiz.  The features I use in Compiz include Negative (Super+N), which flips a window to a negative image for high contrast.  I also use Enhanced Desktop Zoom (Super + Mouse Up/DOwn), which will zoom in the entire desktop, and the Pointer Locator (Super + K), which helps find the pointer by putting a large red X on the screen.
I went to do a fresh install of Ubuntu Mate 24.04 on 2 difference machines, and as soon as I installed Compiz and switched the window manager, panels would not load or work right.  Further reading, it looks like Compiz is no longer being worked on, so I'm thinking its time to find a different Desktop environment.
Does anyone know of a Desktop Environment that has these features (Negative, Enhanced Desktop Zoom, and Pointer Locator)?
Thanks
David

It wasn't really the desktop you relied on, but the WM (or combination).  Mate exists in 24.04 with not that many changes, however you cannot use it with your old WM.  A number of DEs are WM agnostic; or at least will work with many WMs, though some are intended to be used with specific WMs.
